# How to access api.url_for in big Flask-Restful API

Tags: python, flask, python-import, flask-restful

I'm working on a Restful API using Flask-Restful with more resources than I'd like to keep in my app.py. So I've applied the suggested [project structure](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.3/intermediate-usage.html#project-structure). Now I'd like to access [api.url_for()](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.3/api.html#flask_restful.Api.url_for) from a resource to generate some links, but it seems I'd have to `from app import api` to do that.

To avoid circular imports, my current solution is to do a lazy import. But there has be a better way, right?

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from myapi.resources.foo import Foo
from myapi.resources.bar import Bar
from myapi.resources.baz import Baz

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Foo, '/Foo', '/Foo/<str:id>')
api.add_resource(Bar, '/Bar', '/Bar/<str:id>')
api.add_resource(Baz, '/Baz', '/Baz/<str:id>')
```

`resource/foo.py` (`bar.py` respectively):

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from bar import Bar

class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        from app import api
        related = api.url_for(Bar, foo=self.id)
        return {'Foo':self.id, 'related_bar':related}, 200

    def post(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move your imports *down*, to below the `api = Api(app)` line:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

from myapi.resources.foo import Foo
from myapi.resources.bar import Bar
from myapi.resources.baz import Baz

api.add_resource(Foo, '/Foo', '/Foo/<str:id>')
api.add_resource(Bar, '/Bar', '/Bar/<str:id>')
api.add_resource(Baz, '/Baz', '/Baz/<str:id>')
```

Now the `api` name has been defined and you can safely import `from app import api` in your `resources` modules:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from app import api
from bar import Bar

class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        related = api.url_for(Bar, foo=self.id)
        return {'Foo':self.id, 'related_bar':related}, 200

    def post(self):
        pass
```

See the [*Larger Applications* pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) in the Flask documentation.